# Java get subject from JWT token

Tags: java, rest, web-services, oauth-2.0, jwt

I would like to read the JWT token, and get the userID from it.

As I know the userID is equal to "sub" as "subject" in the JWT claims.

```
@GET()
@Path("path")
@RolesAllowed("user")
public String method(    ){

    String userID = jwt.claims.get ("sub");  // or something like this 

}
```

How is it possible?

Comment: use one of the [libraries](https://jwt.io/#libraries-io) and decode the token. Just refer to the documentation of the lib.

Answer (score 2):

If the `userID` is in the "sub" claim, you can receive it in the following way using [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt) library:

```
Long userID = Long.parseLong(Jwts.parser()
  .setSigningKey(secretKey)
  .parseClaimsJws(token)
  .getBody()
  .getSubject());
```

Where `secretKey` is your signing key and `token` is your JWT token.